# Swift animation doesn't update during while loop

Tags: swift, animation

I am new to Swift. I am trying to animate an object within a while loop, but the screen doesn't update until after the while loop is completed.  If I run the function that the while loop is in by repeatedly clicking a button, it does work, but I want it run on its own. I have tried loading the screen every loop, but it didn't work.

```
 func moveBall() {
  while loopnumb <= 100 {
    loopnumb += 1
    print("animation loop cycled \(loopnumb) times")
    
    print("inside of moveball() before startanimation, scratchX is \(scratchX), scratchY is \(scratchY), and the direction is \(direction).")
    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.5, curve: .linear) {
        self.direckEffeck()
        self.scratch.frame = CGRect(x: self.scratchX, y: self.scratchY, width: 240, height: 128)
        print("after and inside of animation command, scratchX is \(self.scratchX), scratchY is \(self.scratchY), and the direction is \(self.direction).")
    }
    animator.startAnimation()
    if checkForOOBX() == true && checkForOOBY() == false {
        direckCheckX()
    }
    if checkForOOBY() == true && checkForOOBX() == false {
        direckCheckY()
    }
    if checkForOOBX() == true && checkForOOBY() == true {
        if direction == 0 && done == false {
            direction = 2
            done = true
        }
        if direction == 1 && done == false {
            direction = 3
            done = true
        }
        if direction == 2 && done == false {
            direction = 0
            done = true
        }
        if direction == 3 && done == false {
            direction = 1
            done = true
        }
        cornerTouches += 1
        print("ebic win, gamer's! the amount of corner touches is \(cornerTouches)")
    }
    done = false
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        self.scratch.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
  }
  loopnumb = 0
}
```

Note that the object I am trying to move is called "scratch", and its coordinates are scratchX, scratchY. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, is the while loop running in the main thread?

Comment: Yes, it is in the main thread

Comment: If you're blocking the main thread (in the while loop) then nothing else can run till it completes

Comment: How would I stop blocking the main thread in this scenario? I've tried searching it on my own, but to no avail

Comment: First, you shouldn't be creating a new `UIViewPropertyAnimator` on each loop, that seems excessive.  One way I might consider is to use a `CADisplayLink` instead, which will provide a call back 60 times a second in sync with the display refresh cycle.  Having said that, may be you should really be looking at sprite kit instead